# RMD: how to create tabbed chunks through loops with plots and tables

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have many similar datasets that I want to output in an RMD file and store each output in a specific tab.

I created two functions that generate a table (using Kable) and a plotly of the ggplot. In order to avoid the repetition of writing them all out (it would take me ages) I tried to write a loop using the cat() function to generate the chunks for me and the output the tables and graphs in the correct tab.

However, although loop I’ve made generates the headers and tabs correctly, it does not output graphs or tables at all. In fact it only occasionally outputs a plot in the first tab and even then often messes up the entire chunk order.

See an example below:

````
```{r,fig.width=6,echo=FALSE,results =“asis”}

types <- c(“mpg”,”cyl”,”hp”)
Headers <- c(“header 1”,”header 2”)

for (i in headers) {
 cat(paste0(“# “,i,”{.tabset} \n”))
  for (j in types) {
   cat(paste0(“# “,j,” \n”))

#this is where the problems begin   
   cat(“```{r} \n”)
   plot(mtcars[j])
   cat("  \n")

 }
}
````

Also, as it stands it seems neither the base R plot works nor the ggplot/kable functions I’ve made.

I’ve been having a lot of trouble with this and am pressed for time for this report so any help would be really appreciated!! If there’s a better way to do this please let me know!

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

With following adjustments your minimal working example gives the desired output:

````
```{r, fig.width=6, echo=FALSE, results ="asis"}

types <- c("mpg","cyl","hp")
headers <- c("header 1","header 2")

for (i in headers) {
  
 cat(paste0("## ",i,"{.tabset} \n"))

  for (j in types) {
   cat(paste0("### ",j," \n"))
    plot(mtcars[j])
    cat("\n\n")

 }
}
```
````

Note that a tab must be one level lower than the associated tabset (e.g. tabset on "level" `##`, tabs on level `###`). In addition, the graph/table must be generated in the codechunk and not delivered to the console with `cat()` (this was at least the case in my applications).

Comment: Hi! So it seems to work for plot but when I try to output kable(mtcars$j) or ggplot wrapped with ggplotly it doesn’t output anything? Even if I wrap them in functions. Any clue what’s going on here and how I can resolve it?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a solution for this either. A somewhat stupid but possibly working solution would be to first generate the graphics/tables you mentioned and save them locally (using `htmltools::save_html()` and then import the locally saved HTML output into RMarkdown-report. However, I am convinced that there is a better solution.